# Walking Path in Python using a Decorator

Tags: path, decorator, python

I was curious on how decorators worked so was seeing if it would work for placing generic functions inside walking a path. I wanted to return the longest segment of integers in space seperated files below the path (and then return this value or possibly print it). Is this possible?

I tried to return things in countL with no success. Then was curious if I placed outside out of the function how this would work. Are Decorators only for printing or can you return from them to get this example to operate properly??

```
def walkPath(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        outside = None
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(args[0]):
            for filename in filenames:
                fn(filename, dirname, outside, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@walkPath
def countL(filename, dirname, outside, path, extension = '.wrd'):
    if (filename[-4:]  == extension):
        with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), 'r') as input:
            data = input.readlines()
        for i in range(len(data)):
            temp = data[i].split()
            if (int(temp[1]) - int(temp[0]) > longest):                
                outside = int(temp[1]) - int(temp[0])
```

This explains what I was doing without the decorator and then was just seeing if you could get the same functionality but making it generic. This means where it wasn't necessarily the longest word in a set of files but maybe a set of files with the word 's' in the filename for example. Just don't know how to handle the external variable longest properly or if that is possible with decorators.

```
def countLength(path, extension = '.wrd'):
    longest = 0
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            if (filename[-4:]  == extension):
                with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), 'r') as input:
                    data = input.readlines()
                for i in range(len(data)):
                    temp = data[i].split()
                    if (int(temp[1]) - int(temp[0]) > longest):
                        longest = int(temp[1]) - int(temp[0])
    return longest
```

Comment: but you don't actually return anything in `wrapper`...

Comment: You don't return anything in `countL` either...

Comment: I tried to offer a useful example, but I can't tell what you actually want from this question. I think you should give one or two examples of a directory structure, the files in it, and the output you want to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is, you are trying to split into the outer loop and its body, but within the loop you had a local variable (`longest`) to compare the numbers. So what you would need to do is to make your inner function aggregate the results. That means the walkPath loop would need to save the result of every call to `fn` and hand it over to the next call, so you can do the comparison *within* `fn`. At the end it should spit out what the last call returned. I guess this is what you were trying to do with `outside`. I also removed the `path` argument from `countL`, because it didn't do anything. You example should work like this:

```
def walkPath(fn):
    def wrapper(outside, *args, **kwargs):
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(args[0]):
            for filename in filenames:
                outside = fn(outside, filename, dirname, *args, **kwargs)
        return outside
    return wrapper

@walkPath
def countL(outside, filename, dirname, extension = '.wrd'):
    if (filename[-4:]  == extension):
        with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), 'r') as input:
            data = input.readlines()
        for i in range(len(data)):
            temp = data[i].split()
            if (int(temp[1]) - int(temp[0]) > outside):                
                outside = int(temp[1]) - int(temp[0])
    return outside
```

You would then have to call something like `countL(0)`.

Comment: This worked but I did need the path because I pass it in as arg[0] to the wrapper function. I updated the example and works great. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide where you want to aggregate and how to return the data. I would do it this way:

```
def walkPath(fn):
    def wrapper(walkroot, *args, **kwargs):
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(walkroot):
            for filename in filenames:
                res = fn(filename, dirname, *args, **kwargs)
                if res is not None: yield res
    return wrapper

@walkPath
def countL(filename, dirname, extension='.wrd'):
    if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == extension:
        with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), 'r') as input:
            data = input.readlines()
        for i in range(len(data)):
            temp = data[i].split()
            return int(temp[1]) - int(temp[0])
```

and now, the caller of `walkPath()` gets a generator which yields a "delta value" from each file. So you can easily find the maximum value with `max(walkPath(...))`

Besides, I changed the extension comparison to

```
if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == extension:
```

provided you `import os` somewhere.

---

Stop. After re-reading the code, I have to ask:

Do you have potentially more than one value pair in a file? If so, we have to make `countL()` return a generator.

```
@walkPath
def countL(filename, dirname, extension='.wrd'):
    if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == extension:
        with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), 'r') as input:
            data = input.readlines()
        for i in range(len(data)):
            temp = data[i].split()
            yield int(temp[1]) - int(temp[0])
```

Now the decorated `countL()` returns a generator which yields generators, so we have to do

```
max(value for filegen in countL(...) for value in filegen)
```

Alternatively, we can change `walkPath()` to

```
def walkPath(fn):
    def wrapper(walkroot, *args, **kwargs):
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(walkroot):
            for filename in filenames:
                for item in fn(filename, dirname, *args, **kwargs):
                    yield item
    return wrapper
```

so that it yields the items of each call to `fn()`. Not it is enough to do

```
max(countL(...))
```

again.

Comment: Think this is what I was after will have to give it a go a little later and let you know. Basically the generator can return anything even a class for example and then externally you can deal with what specifically you want like the max in this case.

Comment: @J Spen Exactly. Basically, the decorator turns a function returning a value into a generator yielding a value per file found during the walk.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work properly like this no matter what i tried. The generator would only be able to call next() once.

Comment: I have made some changes: a) made the parameter passing cleaner, b) use `splitext()` and c) suppress `None` return values which came from the non-existing `else` part of the `if` in `countL()`. I have created 2 files and it works for me now...

Comment: And provided the case that one file can contain multiple value pairs, I have added an alternative implementation (well, actually, 2).